# Webrtc Vulnerable Version

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc

I'm using webrtc android. After some version upload on play store, it's a while the play store shows me an error:

Vulnerable WebRTC Versions: Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security vulnerabilities.

Here is the version that I'm using org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006. Are there any updates on this library? If not, please suggest me an alternative for the Android native WebRTC library.